# ORDS application with no APEX installed trying to access APEX resources

Tags: oracle-ords

I have installed ORDS as the mechanism to request database resources for an ADF application using OHS 12c.

After having created the database connection via command:

```
java -jar ords.war setup --database mydb
```

and mapping the URL to point to it using:

```
java -jar ords.war map-url --type base-path /mydb mydb
```

the application is running as expected and ORDs is doing the job.

However, if I try to go to http://< hotname >/ords/mydb, the request gets re-directed to http://< hotname >/ords/mydb/f?p=4050:1 and - since APEX is not installed - prompts the following error message:

[image: message from webpage]

How can I stop this re-direction from occurring?

Answer (score 1):

APEX is in fact installed to get that message.

To change the redirect for / , edit defaults.xml and set this to the default you prefer

```
  <entry key="misc.defaultPage">/my/new/redirect</entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [if](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56351_01/doc.30/e87809/installing-REST-data-services.htm#AELIG7026) this page helps and look for the following:

1.4.3 Configuring a Doc Root for Non-Application Express Static Resources